# model in codeigniter won't recognize id number

Tags: php, codeigniter

So here is the error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: idnum

Filename: models/model_teacher.php

Line Number: 8
```

this is my controller:

```
 public function teacher(){

   $this->load->model('model_teacher');

   $data['result'] = $this->model_teacher->scoreboard();
   $this->load->view('teacher/teacher', $data);
  }
```

and my model:

```
 class Model_teacher extends CI_Model {

    public function scoreboard() {

        $this->db->where('login_id', $this->input->post('idnum'));
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE login_id = '".$idnum."'");
        return $query->result();

        }
}
```

and the view:

```
<?php
  foreach ($result as $row) {
            echo $row->login_id."<br>";
            echo $row->lname."<br>";
        }
?>
```

and don't know what is wrong with this code. please bear with me, i'm still a newbie at using codeigniter. thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't get directly in model you have to first get in controller
**Controller**

```
   public function teacher(){
$id  = $this->input->post('idnum');

   $this->load->model('model_teacher');

   $data['result'] = $this->model_teacher->scoreboard($id);
   $this->load->view('teacher/teacher', $data);
  }
```

**Model**`

```
public function scoreboard($idnum) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE login_id = '".$idnum."'");
    return $query->result();

    }`
```

This is the code you can use

Comment: thanks for the reply.. there's no error. however whenever i echo the values it will not print. 

by the way this is my view:
<?php
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row->login_id."<br>";
    echo $row->lname."<br>";
   }
?>

Comment: You can test it at your controller by using 
print_r($data);
die;
before 
 $this->load->view('teacher/teacher', $data);

Comment: this is the only thiing that will print: "Array ( [result] => Array ( ) ) ".. it didn't print the data in teacher table.. :(((

Comment: If you are getting blank then it may possible that there is no data  or its have some problem in the condition check.
Please copy the query and run it in the sql table in phpmyadmin it will gives you the error.

Comment: I run the query and no record shows but I did actually put some data in that table. I have two table the user_account table and teacher table. and i get the (firstname,lastname,middlename, etc.) in the teacher table using the id from user_account table. does it make sense? i don't know if my query is right. please help!!!

Comment: You can use join for getting this data

Comment: but isn't join used for having a foreign key in another table? but i don't actually have one on either of the table. the thing is do you know a query that will compare the POST['login_id'] and the login_id from the teacher table and thus i will echo the data from teacher table?

Comment: will you please send me your database structure

Answer (score 1):

Change as following:

In Controller

```
 public function teacher(){
   $this->load->model('model_teacher');
   $idNum = $this->input->post('idnum');
   $data['result'] = $this->model_teacher->scoreboard($idNum);
   $this->load->view('teacher/teacher', $data);
  }
```

In Model

```
   public function scoreboard($idNum) {
      $this->db->where('login_id', $idNum);
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE login_id = '".$idnum."'");
      return $query->result();
   }
```

Comment: Nothing in codeigniter prevents accessing $this->input->post() in model. It's just a bad practice. The post params should be properly cleaned and validated in controller before loading your model and passing it on

Answer (score 0):

Would be better if you  pass it from controller to model

```
$id = $this->input->post('idnum');
$data['result'] = $this->model_teacher->scoreboard($id);
```

and model:-

```
public function scoreboard($id) {
  //$this->db->where('login_id', $id);
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE login_id = '".$id."'");
  return $query->result();
}
```

Also you haven't define anywhere `$idnum` so notices comes up

Comment: thanks for the reply @rakesh . there's no error anymore. thanks for that. however if i echo, the values won't print. by the way this is my view:<?php foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row->login_id."<br>";
    echo $row->lname."<br>";
   }?>

Comment: check your result finding some rows by echo or print